# How do TextFields behave as FirstResponder when placed inside TableViewCells and scrolled out of view?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Assume we have `UITableView` holding a large number of custom `UITableViewCell`s which contain `UITextField`s and/or `UITextView`s.

We randomly tab on any cell an the text control inside becomes the FirstResponder. The keyboard appears and we can type some text. Everything is fine.

**Is there any reliable information on what happens with the TextField when the cell is re-used for another cell?**

In `tableView.cellForRowAt:indexPath` the cells are dequeued using `dequeueReusableCell`. Is it my responsibility to keep track on which cell contained the FirstResponder and resign / reset it when the cell is scrolled out of view / back into view as I do for my custom view model?

I ran different test and it seems that this is handled automatically somehow. However, I would like to be sure. Could be coincidence that I did not ran into any problems in my tests.